# Google TV Emulater - Facebook Issue

Tags: facebook, google-tv

I am trying to access Facebook in Google TV emulator.

1. Facebook SDK is working on all android platforms but not on Google TV emulator. Is Facebook SDK supported on Google TV. The login page crashes.
2. Also not able to open https://www.facebook.com

Is there any specific setting we need to do?

Can you please let me know is Sony gs7 Google TV opens the URL. Here is stacktrace:

```
12-06 14:18:34.820: E/sighandler(1256): FailureSignalHandler for signal 4.  Code 2.
12-06 14:18:34.820: E/sighandler(1256): Fault Address: 0xb7330fc8.
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256): --- Stack trace: ---
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256): PC: @ 0xb7330fc8  (unknown)
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0xb766c4db        352
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0xb783540c        976
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0xb73311d3         80
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d9da2a5         64
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d5ec8a1         80
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d5ede43        112
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d827c5a         48
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d82553f         80   
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d825b07         80
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d825c69         48
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d8267aa        192
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d815d2a         96
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d88b5ea        928
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d891633        720
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d884379        272
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d8699c1         32
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87c8c0        144
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87ee64        128
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d883c7d        272
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d8699c1         32
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d890f22        720
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d884379        272
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d8699c1         32
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87c8c0        144
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87ee64        128
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d883c7d        272
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d8699c1         32
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87c8c0        144
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87ee64        128
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d883c7d        272
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d8699c1         32
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87c8c0        144
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87ee64        128
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d883c7d        272
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d8699c1         32
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87c8c0        144
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87ee64        128
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d883c7d        272
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d8699c1         32
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87c8c0        144
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87ee64        128
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d883c7d        272
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d8699c1         32
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87c8c0        144
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87ee64        128
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d883c7d        272
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d8699c1         32
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87c8c0        144
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87ee64        128
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d883c7d        272
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d8699c1         32
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87c8c0        144
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87ee64        128
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d883c7d        272
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d8699c1         32
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87c8c0        144
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d87ee64        128
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d883c7d        272
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d8699c1         32
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d927522        160
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d7d86fa        176
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d7d19c2         32
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d809c6b         80
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256):     @ 0x9d809ccf         32
12-06 14:18:34.830: E/sighandler(1256): --- Memory Map: ----
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are working on improvements to the Google TV emulator - there is an upcoming (very soon) update to the emulator that may address some of your issues. The site you indicated does load correctly on a physical Google TV (tested with Vizio Co-Star).

Can you provide a log dump of the crash?

Comment: It loads on my Sony Google TV just fine.